# Deploying docker on gcp on port 22 using container optimized os

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

Currently, I want to deploy an sftp server on port 22 for gcp platform. I'd like to deploy an sftp dockerized image on port 22. The container optimized OS uses the port 22 similiar to linux instances.

Do I need to update the sshd_config to a different port? Is that all that's needed? Thanks.

I did update sshd_config but it is not persistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this escenario is not posible with Container Optimized OS as
it includes a locked-down firewall [1], so you will be unable to use other SSH port, and /etc path between others is read-only.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/features-and-benefits#features_and_benefits

Comment: Sounds about right as of now. I could not find any method or documentation.